# Most common network services statistics?

Tags: networking, service

I'm looking for some statistics about the most common used LAN network services... does anyone know a source for this kind of information?

Is there somekind of report about the current network services tendencies?

Thanks

Comment: Define "network service" in this context.

Comment: Services like dns, dhcp, smb, etc.

Comment: "network services" statistics of you, me, your neighbor, the internet?  who?. I have a feeling there is more to this question, as one of my cohorts would say: "What is the real question?"

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ntop.org/news.php

Depending on where you set ntop up to collect data it should be able to show you network usage.

"ntop is a network traffic probe that shows the network usage, similar to what the popular top Unix command does. ntop is based on libpcap and it has been written in a portable way in order to virtually run on every Unix platform and on Win32 as well."